# why should we use import React from 'react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

i am learning React js in **case ii** App.js module i have to import React because the *render()* method is used to convert JSX to dom elements how ever in Person.js we are creating a arrow function and we are exporting it so that it can be imported and used in the App modules render function how ever in App module we have React imported and it will convert the JSX  in module  person 
and gets rendered on DOM but when it throws an error when we remove the below code in Person.js

```
import React from 'react' in Person.js
```

it throws error

*React' must be in scope when using JSX*   if we declare JSX in the methods (like render ) provided from React class it should give an error.

can someone please explain

i)why do we need to import react in Person.js?

ii)why was it throwing error when we remove the above code?

case i)

> Person.js

```
 import React from 'react'

 const person = () => {
 return <p>This is person module used inside app module</p>
 };

 export default person
```

case ii)

> App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css'
import Person from './Person/Person'

class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>this is app module and i am being used as the root component</h1>
     <Person/>
  </div>
);}}

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks!. can you explain how the compiler has understood JSX is being used in Person.js

Comment: Static analysis allows Babel to detect JSX (via some plugins). Then it uses more plugins to actually break it down and parse/transform JSX into `React.createElement`.

Comment: thanks this  comment helped in knowing how JSX is understood by compiler

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you give some JSX to Babel, [you will see that JSX is just sugar for `React.createElement` calls](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwBwfAKgFglgzgAngkBTATnA9gOwQWywBMBXAG1QRLlSKRzhiMoEMQQDjzVgB6cIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=react&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.12.15&externalPlugins=). This is why we need to import React if we use JSX.

**Input**

```
<p>This is person module used inside app module</p>
```

**Output**

```
/*#__PURE__*/
React.createElement("p", null, "This is person module used inside app module");
```

Comment: Just an update: React 17 and some older specified major versions now include a new JSX transform that does not require this explicit React import. See https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

Answer (score 3):

When you are trying to use jsx in your javascript file your normal compiler as well as even babel couldnot understand it. Although normal compiler never understand it. But anyhow you want to say your compiler I am providing you a jsx in the file.

```
import React from 'react';
```

Above is the way to instruct babel go on, its a easy task for you now.

```
<p>This is person module used inside app module</p>
```

Above is a jsx statment. So when ever you use it you will require React imported.
Similarly we donot need it in actions, reducers and so on in many places because we dont have jsx there.