# React Native Navigation - Putting navigationOptions of Stack Navigator inside Bottom Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

As said in the [documentation of the createBottomTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html), the screens inside the navigator can contain a variable called `navigationOptions` in which they configure different settings. I did this successfully with my own components, however, when I tried to put a Stack Navigator inside the Bottom Tab Navigator and with that, I encountered a problem.

**PROBLEM:** I'm not sure where to put the `navigationOptions` variable when creating a Stack Navigator to customize the `tabIcon` of the Bottom Tab Navigator that corresponds to that Stack Navigator I created.

I tried this: (Code Snippet #1)

```
const navigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        'MainKYCScreen': {
            screen: KYCScreen
        }
    },
    {
    initialRouteName: "MainKYCScreen"
    },
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(navigator);

// navigationOptions - start
AppContainer.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <NavButtonContainer focused={focused}>
            <KYCIcon status={KYCIcon.TYPE_RED} />
        </NavButtonContainer>
    )
};
// navigationOptions - end

export default AppContainer;
```

And this: (Code Snippet #2)

```
const navigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        'MainKYCScreen': {
            screen: KYCScreen
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "MainKYCScreen"
    },
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(navigator);

export default class KYCNavigator extends AppContainer {
    // navigationOptions - start
    static navigationOptions = {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <NavButtonContainer focused={focused}>
                <KYCIcon status={KYCIcon.TYPE_RED} />
            </NavButtonContainer>
        )
    }
    // navigationOptions - end
}
```

Removing the code from `navigationOptions - start` to `navigationOptions - end`. Putting it there seem to return an odd error.

[image]

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your error, just import React from 'react' package.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
```

For the explanation why it should be imported, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388723/why-should-we-use-import-react-from-react) could explain why.

Comment: NICE! I tried it and it worked! :D I used code snippet #2 and just appended the import above the code. THANKS!