# Confusion with default import of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To import React we write `import React from 'react'`.

But this is a default export right ? So if I change its name to something else other than **React** it should also work. But it doesn't work. Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: Related: [why should we use import React from 'react'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51388723/1048572)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essentially, JSX compilers (like Babel/TypeScript) convert the JSX code to pure JavaScript.

For example, the following JSX code:

```
const Element = () => (
    <div>
        Hey there
    </div>
);
```

is compiled into:

```
const Element = () => (
    React.createElement("div", null, "Hey there")
);
```

Which is now valid JavaScript that can be parsed by the browser.

As you may have noticed, it uses the `React.createElement` function to create the `div`. This is why changing the name of the import doesn't work - the compiler still tries to use `React`.

Babel lets you [configure this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx#pragma) using the `pragma` option, if desired, allowing you to use a different function name.

TypeScript [can do the same](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) using the `jsxFactory` compiler option.

Comment: Awesome that you cited `pragma` option, there are also another useful options in the link you provided, thanks @odensc

Comment: @Junius L. This is the reason why changing the import name doesn't work, which is what the question was asking. If you don't use JSX, you can change the import to whatever you want.

Comment: @Junius L. Because if they were not using JSX then there wouldn't be any issue. This is the only reasonable answer to the question, barring any misconfiguration of the bundler.

Comment: This question is very specifically about the default export of the React library, not just imports in general.

Answer (score 0):

It works so, as you use Babel, or something similar, to translate JSX. 
So when you input something like this:

```
function AComponent() {
 return <div>Hello world</div>
}
```

You will get the next transpiled code:

```
"use strict";

function AComponent() {
  return React.createElement("div", null, "Hello world");
}
```

By this reason you should use the definite name of React. 
You can try it here: https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=AQ4MwVwOwYwFwJYHsrAIIGEkFsAOKBTKOACgEpgBvAKFBACcC4J7UAeAEwQDcA-ACQIAbIUmAB3JPSEc2Aei59aoAL5A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.4&externalPlugins=